# Space between divs and floating image

Tags: html, css, image

I am making a portfolio website and I want to place two divs with little horizontal space between each other and a floating circle image in the center between them as so. The divs are the lighter ones. I was wondering how to style them and the image so that it floats betweet the divs with a little space.
I've tried

[image]

```css
img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
}

div {
  z-index: 90;
}
```

Please help me style these. I have no other ideas

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute` and `z-index`

```css
body {
  background: #BD9EA4;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: #E6DADC;
  z-index: 1;
}

div:first-child {
  z-index: 2;
}

span {
  background: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #E6DADC;
}
```

```html
<div><span></span></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: how do I style the img so that it fits inside the span, mine goes away